# Converting hex string to packet in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

My aim is to sniff a packet from a `pcap` file, modify the last 4 bytes of the packet and send it. For now, I'm doing like this:

```
from scapy.all import *
from struct import pack
from struct import unpack

pkt = sniff(offline="my.pcap", count=1)

pkt_hex = str(pkt)
# getting output like '\x00\x04\x00 ... ... \x06j]'

last_4 = unpack('!I',pkt_hex[-4:])[0]
# getting last 4 bytes and converting it to integer

rest = pkt_hex[:-4]
# getting whole packet in string except last 4 bytes

new_pkt = rest + pack('>I',(last_4+1))
# created the whole packet again with last 4 bytes incremented by 1
# the new string is like '\x00\x04\x00 ... ... \x06j^'
```

Now My problem is I'm unable to convert it back to a layered packet object of Scapy and hence unable to send it using `sendp`.

PS: I've to recalculate the checksum. But once I'll convert it to a packet object, I can recalculate the checksum following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953371/how-to-calculate-a-packet-checksum-without-sending-it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rebuild the packet using the class of the original packet, however there are other errors in your program.

The [official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) on the `sniff` function states that it returns a list:

> `sniff(prn=None, lfilter=None, count=0, store=1, offline=None, L2socket=None, timeout=None)`
>
> > Sniffs packets from the network and return them in a packet list.

Therefore, rather than extracting the packet with `pkt_hex = str(pkt)`, the correct form to extract the packet is `pkt_hex = str(pkt[0])`.

Once that is done, you are free to alter the packet, update its checksum (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648093/3903832)) and rebuild it using the class of the original packet, as follows (note my comments):

```
from scapy.all import *
from struct import pack
from struct import unpack

pkts = sniff(offline="my.pcap", count=1)

pkt = pkts[0] # <--- NOTE: correctly extract the packet

del pkt.chksum # <--- NOTE: prepare for checksum recalculation
del pkt[TCP].chksum # <--- NOTE: prepare for TCP checksum recalculation (depends on the transport layer protocol in use)

pkt_hex = str(pkt)
# getting output like '\x00\x04\x00 ... ... \x06j' <--- NOTE: there is no trailing ']'

last_4 = unpack('!I',pkt_hex[-4:])[0]
# getting last 4 bytes and converting it to integer

rest = pkt_hex[:-4]
# getting whole packet in string except last 4 bytes

new_hex_pkt = rest + pack('>I',(last_4+1))
# created the whole packet again with last 4 bytes incremented by 1
# the new string is like '\x00\x04\x00 ... ... \x06k' <--- NOTE: 'j' was incremented to 'k' (rather than ']' to '^')

new_pkt = pkt.__class__(new_hex_pkt) # <--- NOTE: rebuild the packet and recalculate its checksum

sendp(new_pkt) # <--- NOTE: send the new packet
```

**EDIT:**

Note that this doesn't preserve the packet's timestamp, which would change to the current time. In order to retain the original timestamp, assign it to `new_pkt.time`:

```
new_pkt.time = pkt.time
```

However, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680019/3903832), even after changing the packet's timestamp and sending it, the updated timestamp won't be reflected in the received packet on the other end since [the timestamp is set in the receiving machine as the packet is received](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Timestamps).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I'm sniffing only 1 packet, it works fine without `pkt = pkt[0]` also. No doubt having it also doesn't affect the program.